# Call same the function when promise is resolved or rejected in JS for loop

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is my function which returns a promise:

```
function myFunction(i){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i)
      resolve(i)
    },i*1000)
  })
}
```

I want to call `myFunction` serially in each iteration of the loop when the function's promise is resolved or rejected.

```
// rough idea but it doesn't work 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  myFunction(i).then(function(){
     myFunction(i)
  }).catch(function(){
     myFunction(i)
  })
}
```

How I can do this with ES5 syntax?

Comment: You can use a polyfill, so Promise is also compatible with older browsers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

Comment: Why don't you want to use the normal modern syntax? What promise library are you using in ES5?

Comment: how could it work?  You didn't even set up the initial promise correctly.  You need to follow the instructions of how to use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: As your loop is written, you’re running an identical  function call twice `myFunction(i)`. Is that really what you want?